# producer send msg to rabbitmq, when does rabbitmq broker send confirm message? Is before broker storage or after

Tags: rabbitmq

Bg:
Producer send a message to rabbitmq, its true rabbitmq will send a confirm msessage to producer. And rabbitmq will storage the message in exchange,queue. I have a question, when does the rabbitmq store the message, is before send confirm message or after that? I guess the workflow is broker storage the message first and then send confirm message, does it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html#publisher-confirms. If you use publisher confirms, the broker will send an ack when the message has been stored.